# Socket permission error attempting to start Hive

Tags: hadoop, hive

I've set up Hive and Hadoop on a local development machine. I've configured Hive to use MySql as it's metadatastore. When I try and start Hive I get the following exception:

```
`C:\Users\<USER>hive
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/data-engineering/hadoop331/share/hadoop/common/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.30.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/data-engineering/hive3/lib/log4j-slf4j-impl-2.10.0.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory]
2023-01-02 18:55:44,239 INFO conf.HiveConf: Found configuration file file:/C:/data-engineering/hive3/conf/hive-site.xml
Hive Session ID = 228b9d9a-c6aa-4d61-adaa-ade6f0b1d878
2023-01-02 18:55:49,590 INFO SessionState: Hive Session ID = 228b9d9a-c6aa-4d61-adaa-ade6f0b1d878

Logging initialized using configuration in jar:file:/C:/data-engineering/hive3/lib/hive-common-3.0.0.jar!/hive-log4j2.properties Async: true
2023-01-02 18:55:49,834 INFO SessionState:
Logging initialized using configuration in jar:file:/C:/data-engineering/hive3/lib/hive-common-3.0.0.jar!/hive-log4j2.properties Async: true
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.net.SocketException: Call From HHC12368/172.21.160.1 to 0.0.0.0:19000 failed on socket exception: java.net.SocketException: Permission denied: no further information; For more details see:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/SocketException
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.start(SessionState.java:644)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.beginStart(SessionState.java:585)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.run(CliDriver.java:747)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.main(CliDriver.java:683)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:323)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:236)
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Call From HHC12368/172.21.160.1 to 0.0.0.0:19000 failed on socket exception: java.net.SocketException: Permission denied: no further information; For more details see:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/SocketException
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.wrapWithMessage(NetUtils.java:913)
        at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.wrapException(NetUtils.java:871)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.getRpcResponse(Client.java:1577)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1519)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1416)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine2$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine2.java:242)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine2$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine2.java:129)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy28.getFileInfo(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.getFileInfo(ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.java:965)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:422)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler$Call.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:165)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler$Call.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:157)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler$Call.invokeOnce(RetryInvocationHandler.java:95)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:359)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy29.getFileInfo(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.getFileInfo(DFSClient.java:1731)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$29.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:1752)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$29.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:1749)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystemLinkResolver.resolve(FileSystemLinkResolver.java:81)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.getFileStatus(DistributedFileSystem.java:1764)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.exists(FileSystem.java:1760)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Utilities.ensurePathIsWritable(Utilities.java:4483)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.createRootHDFSDir(SessionState.java:753)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.createSessionDirs(SessionState.java:694)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.start(SessionState.java:620)
        ... 9 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Permission denied: no further information
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:715)
        at org.apache.hadoop.net.SocketIOWithTimeout.connect(SocketIOWithTimeout.java:206)
        at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.connect(NetUtils.java:586)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.setupConnection(Client.java:701)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.setupIOstreams(Client.java:822)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.access$3800(Client.java:414)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.getConnection(Client.java:1647)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1463)`
```

Given the nature of the exception message I'm assuming it's got something to do with Hive talking to Hadoop as my Hadoop core-site.xml specifies:

```
<configuration>
   <property>
     <name>fs.default.name</name>
     <value>hdfs://0.0.0.0:19000</value>
   </property>
</configuration>
```

Any ideas? Honestly, I feel it's 1 step forwards 2 steps back getting this set up!

Comment: 0.0.0.0 is not a routable ip address. You need to configure hdfs with one. Plus, Namenode starts on port 9000 by default... Also `hive`  command doesn't start the Hive server, only a client session. Plus, you don't technically need hadoop installed to run Hive

Comment: Thanks @OneCricketeer I have this sorted-ish now. The IP address was part of the problem.

Comment: Feel free to answer below with your complete solution

Comment: @JoeIngle if you are interested in dockerized version then I have created one here with latest hive and tez. https://hub.docker.com/repository/docker/raiddocker/apache_hive/general Let me know if this works in Docker for Windows

Answer (score 0):

The resolution to this, as alluded to be @OneCricketeer, was to set a correct value for the property fs.default.name in core-site.xml.

```
    <configuration>
       <property>
         <name>fs.default.name</name>
         <value>hdfs://{HDFS_IP_ADDRESS}:9000</value>
       </property>
    </configuration>
```